# express js render object variables to webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an object that I am trying to print its key and value variables onto my browser. the object looks like this

```
{ data:
[ { type: 'product',
   name: 'test-prod-2018',
   slug: '1',
   description: 'This is a test Product',
  } ],
links:
{ current: 'https://example.com',
 first: 'https://tutorial.com',
 last: null },
meta:
{ results: { total: 1, all: 1 },
  } }
```

In my app.js, I am using

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
var title = Mystore.Products.All().then((products) => {
    console.log(products);
});

res.render('index', {
    title: title
});
});
```

In my index.ejs i am using

```
<h1>
    <%= title %>
</h1>
```

This prints to the screen

```
[object Promise]
```

How can I list information from the data part of my object onto the screen for example if I wanted to display the name and description? The screen would display

```
<h1><%= title:name %></h1>
<h1><%= title:description %></h1>
```

Comment: I believe you're setting the variable `title` equal to the `.then` promise, since you do not have a return value in the promise. Have you tried doing the `res.render()` inside of your promise and removing the variable assignment? i.e. `res.render('index', { title: products });`

Comment: I put the res.render('index', { title: products }); inside of my promise and it returns [object Object]

Comment: Is this on your node server or your frontend?  If you wanted to view what is returned with a server side console log and it's displaying `[Object object]`, `console.log(JSON.stringify(products))`

Answer (score 0):

Ok after looking at your question for a second, I think I understand what you're trying to do and what you are currently doing.

You're setting `title` equal to the value of the `then` Promise, since there is no return value (I'm unsure if promises can implement the behavior you're looking for)

Even if you wanted just one title from your products, currently the database query seems to return all products, with each product having a title, name, etc attribute. So you'll need to send all the products to the front and iterate over them, or query one specific product and send that to the front. I'm also unsure about the `product` vs `title` namespacing is, so I've just gone with `product` for the example code below

#### Try this:

**index.js**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Mystore.Products.All().then((products) => {
        res.render('index', {
            products: products
        });
    });
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<% products.forEach(function(product) { %>
    <% for (key in product) %>
        <h1>Key: <%= key %></h1>
        <h2>Value: <%= product[key] %></h2>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```